# Difference between value = Field vs Field = value in sql

Tags: sql

I have been asked a tricky SQL question in an Interview.

```
Select * from Employee where EmployeeId = 23
Select * from Employee where 23 = EmployeeId
```

Please help me finding difference between above statements, is it about there indexes?

Comment: For the equality operator and assuming a sane optimizer, they should be evaluated identically.

Comment: Modern RDBMS are smart enough to treat both `where` as being the *same*; if you want to force *full scan* (no index use on `EmployeeId`), put it as `EmployeeId * 1 = 23` or alike

Comment: There is no difference at all. None whatsoever

Comment: What was the "right" answer according to the interview?

Comment: @JonScott I replied! i don't have clue right now, i'll check its execution plan. Interviewer smiles and jumps to next :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this in SQL Server but I assume each optimiser works in the same logical way. The two queries do the same thing:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employees (ID   INT IDENTITY(1, 1), name NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES('Test1'), ('Test2');

SELECT * FROM #Employees WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT * FROM #Employees WHERE 1 = ID;
```

Without an index on the table it does the same, a table scan :

[image]

If you add an index and then do the same two querys you get the same plan but with an index seek rather than table scan

```
ALTER TABLE #Employees ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID] ASC);

SELECT * FROM #Employees WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT * FROM #Employees WHERE 1 = ID;
```

[image]

if your going to test it too, remember to drop the table :)

```
DROP TABLE #Employees;
```